# querySelectorAll or options for h4 text targetting on drop down menu? Simple Enough?

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to set up a variable in GTM to only display this h4 "Service" text in this specific drop-down by running a basic javascript command `document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-menu li.ddc-span4 h4")` and it returns a (12) NodeList. However, I want to specifically target NodeList 5: with the text "Service".
I can't narrow it down anymore with CSS as I can't edit the website at all. If I could I would make a unique class name for it and be done.

How would I go about targeting this h4 text a little better?

I intend to use this as a filter for my GTM Trigger.

[image]
[image]

I'm a novice with javascript coding but I understand how to reverse engineer some of it to make it work. I think I need a different approach/code because it finds the very first h4 tag in the DOM and displays the text as the variable because that's what this code does.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Look at the documentation: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7683362#custom_javascript

Answer (score 0):

Your query is returning an array of the nodes so all you need to do is save it as a variable and then access that specific index.

```
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-menu li.ddc-span4 h4");
const service = nodes[5];
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help with this. I'm following your instructions.

When I go to save this in GTM it states: The javaScript must define a function with a return value. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have absolutely no experience with GTM but if it wants the return value to come from a function then just function () {
  return document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-menu li.ddc-span4 h4")[5]
}

Comment: This comes back as a  
[object HTMLHeadingElement] and not "Service" hmmm

Comment: This does give me the results that the [object HTMLHeadingElement] is in fact an h4 tag but I needed to add a little more code to get the desired text results. Thanks for the help @Martin Balke

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with this enough I figured out what I needed to do to get the text results returned.

```
function text()
{return document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-menu li.ddc-span4 h4")[5].innerText;}
```

Or

```
function text()
{return document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-menu li.ddc-span4 h4")[5].innerHTML;}
```